# In node.js, is there a name for the global object (or the head object)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If the environment is the browser, then we can use

```
<script>
    console.log(this === window);
</script>
```

to test that the `this` keyword points to the `window` object, which is also the global object (or some book calls it the "head object").

What if in node.js, is there such a name similar to `window`, so that

```
console.log(this === globalObjectName);
```

will print out true?

Answer (score 3):

There is `global`.  And this returns true when run from the main level:

```
this === global
```

But depending on what you are trying to test for:

```
require.main === module
```

may be more helpful.  This tells you whether your module is running as the main one or is being "required".

Comment: this is somewhat strange that, if I run on Bash on a Macbook, for `node -e "console.log(this === global);"` then I get a `true`, but if I have a `foo.js` file containing just one line `console.log(this === global);` and then run in Bash `node foo.js`, then it prints out `false`

Comment: Hmmm, yes, interesting.  When running in bash more, `this` is just `{}`, but equal to `global` in interactive mode or via `node -e`.  This behavior must be caused by `require` and how it changes `this`.  `require.main === module` is true using bash mode, which is typically what is used to determine whether you are running your module in bash mode, or being required by something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is the **global** object.

You can find this in [Node API](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html).