# What's the basis for setInterval in node.js? (the equivalent of window)

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a browser window, `setInterval` is a function that can be accessed globally, but really belongs under [`window`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) Thus:

```
window.setInterval === setInterval
"true"
```

node.js has no default window object, yet it has a `setInterval` function accessed globally. What's the node.js equivalent here (if there is any) to window? Is there some `objectName` that I can use `[objectName].setInterval` instead of calling the function directly?

The documentation [doesn't mention anything](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg) about it (besides saying they're global).

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Comment: thanks @JonathanLonowski, the explanation in that link makes sense out of it, too: `In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope [...] In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; var something inside a Node module will be local to that module.` - so, in other words, `global` has to be the top-level for `setInterval`. If it was in a module it wouldn't be available globally

Comment: possible duplicate of [In node.js, is there a name for the global object (or the head object)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241167/in-node-js-is-there-a-name-for-the-global-object-or-the-head-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global object in Node.js can be accessed by the name `global`.

```
> global.setTimeout
[Function]
```